# SQL%FOUND not reacting to cursor results

Tags: plsql, oracle11gr2

Need to write a procedure with input country_id that returns all departments in that country, if none are found, it must return "none found in country + country_id" (my return string will be in dutch), i got most of the code just the sql%found does not interact with the cursor the way i thought it would, I would like to know what causes this.

Tried changing the = TRUE to != TRUE,still gives me the output as if sql%found was false

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE country_dept
    (p_land_id    IN    countries.country_id%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN 
(
    SELECT department_name
        FROM departments
    WHERE location_id IN 
        (
        SELECT location_Id
            FROM locations
            WHERE country_id IN 
            (
            SELECT country_id
                FROM countries
                WHERE country_id = p_land_id
            )
        )
)

        LOOP
        IF SQL%FOUND = TRUE THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.department_name);      
        ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Er zijn geen departementen gevestigd in het land met id ' || p_land_id);
    END IF;
END;
/
```

I found this solution but it's quite nasty

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE country_dept
    (p_land_id    IN    countries.country_id%TYPE)
AS
    v_number NUMBER :=0;
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN 
(
    SELECT department_name
        FROM departments
    WHERE location_id IN 
        (
        SELECT location_Id
            FROM locations
            WHERE country_id IN 
            (
            SELECT country_id
                FROM countries
                WHERE country_id = p_land_id
            )
        )
)
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.department_name);
            v_number := 1;
        END LOOP;
        IF v_number != 1 THEN       
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Er zijn geen departementen gevestigd in thet land met id ' || p_land_id);
        END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is the right one, for this reason:

The cursor loop is a handy way of opening a cursor and closing it automatically, without need to check if a value was found. Within the bounds of the loop, a record is always present.

Because of this, we end up doing things like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE country_dept
    (p_land_id    IN    countries.country_id%TYPE)
AS
    found BOOLEAN := false; -- Note use of BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN 
(
    SELECT department_name
        FROM departments
    WHERE location_id IN 
        (
        SELECT location_Id
            FROM locations
            WHERE country_id IN 
            (
            SELECT country_id
                FROM countries
                WHERE country_id = p_land_id
            )
        )
)
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.department_name);
            found := true;
        END LOOP;
        IF not found THEN       
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Er zijn geen departementen gevestigd in thet land met id ' || p_land_id);
        END IF;
END;
/
```

Note the usage of a Boolean value instead of a numeric flag.
Also, I am assuming that you will turn this into a function and return results somehow, instead of using `DBMS_OUTPUT`... though there are plenty of production applications out there that use `DBMS_OUTPUT`.

Now, the alternate approach that doesn't use a cursor loop is like this:

```
declare
  cursor c is select 'Hello World!' as phrase from dual where 1=2;
  v_phrase varchar2(100);
begin
  open c;
  fetch c into v_phrase;
  if c%NOTFOUND then
    v_phrase := 'Not found!';
  end if;
  close c;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_phrase);
end;
/
```

In this case we are opening the cursor explicitly, fetching, and then checking if something was found.

We have to explicitly close the cursor too. If we are expecting multiple values then we need to wrap everything in a loop and add a `EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND` somewhere. All in all it's pretty nasty.

Neither is really pretty, but I would go with the cursor loop and Boolean flag since it avoids the manual operations necessary when working with an explicit cursor.